# The purpose of using bind undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I was reading the source code [here](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/blob/master/src/iframeResizer.js) about iframe resizer. And got extremely confused on this snippet in the `factory()` function :

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
                    document.querySelectorAll( target || 'iframe' ),
                    init.bind(undefined, options)
                );
```

the `factory()` function :

```
function factory(){
    function init(options,element){
        function chkType(){
            if(!element.tagName) {
                throw new TypeError('Object is not a valid DOM element');
            } else if ('IFRAME' !== element.tagName.toUpperCase()) {
                throw new TypeError('Expected <IFRAME> tag, found <'+element.tagName+'>');
            }
        }

        if(element) {
            debugger
            chkType();
            setupIFrame(element, options);
            iFrames.push(element);
        }
    }

    var iFrames;

    setupRequestAnimationFrame();
    setupEventListeners();

    return function iFrameResizeF(options,target){
        iFrames = []; //Only return iFrames past in on this call

        switch (typeof(target)){
        case 'undefined':
        case 'string':
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(
                document.querySelectorAll( target || 'iframe' ),
                init.bind(undefined, options)
            );
            break;
        case 'object':
            init(options,target);
            break;
        default:
            throw new TypeError('Unexpected data type ('+typeof(target)+')');
        }

        return iFrames;
    };
}
```

it seems the `element` is iframe element in the `init()` function. Why `init.bind(undefined, options)` got the `element` parameter passed to the init() function? Where does this element comes from?

Answer (score 0):

`.bind()` creates a new function, whose `this` context will be set to the first parameter, and other arguments will be set to the following parameters. To illustrate what that means:

```
function foo(bar, baz) {}

var f = foo.bind({});
f(1, 2);
```

Calling `f` here, `this` will be set to `{}`, `bar` to `1` and `baz` to `2`.

```
var f = foo.bind({}, 1);
f(2);
```

This actually has the same result, `bar` is `1` and `baz` is `2`.

```
var f = foo.bind({}, 1, 2);
f();
```

Again, same result.

You can not only `bind` the value of `this`, you can also bind arguments.

So:

```
init.bind(undefined, options)
```

`init` apparently doesn't need `this`, so `undefined` is used to simply skip over that parameter, and the first argument to `init` is bound to be `options`. Whoever is going to call this bound function later may pass additional arguments. `bind` here is used to bind the first parameter; you simply have to pass something, *anything*, for the `this` argument first.

Comment: But where does `element` come from in the `init()` function? how does it get passed to that function??

Comment: The bound `init` is used as callback for `forEach`; so `forEach` is iterating over `document.querySelectorAll( target || 'iframe' )` and will pass each `element` to the bound `init` in turn.

Comment: It's essentially equivalent to `document.querySelectorAll( target || 'iframe' ).forEach(element => init(options, element))`; however, `querySelectorAll` does not return an `Array`, hence doesn't have `forEach`, hence this workaround is used.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how to use the API of this factory, since it'll clarify where the element comes from.
Basically, calling the factory function, `factory()`, will return the function iFrameResizeF(). You can then call that function with either one or two parameters.

With one parameter, you can either send it the options, or a string that is a css selector. 
If you send it the options, it will bind init() on all iframes in the DOM with those options.
If you send it a string, it will bind init() on all elements that selector gets, without any options.

With two parameters, it'll just bind init() on all those elements with all those options.

Once you then run the init of that element, the correct options will be already selected.

So in code it's something like:

```
var useFactory = factory();
// Two parameters
useFactory( {"option1" : "value1", "option2" : "value2"}, "selectorString" );
// Or only parameters so all iframes are affected
useFactory( {"option1" : "value1", "option2" : "value2"} );
// Or only a selector so the options will be set to undefined for all elements matching the selector
useFactory( "selectorString" );
```

Then somewhere else in the code, those init functions on those elements will probably be called.